# How to set a minimum width of 1mm for my shape in illustrator (Laser cut)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, line-art, laser-cutting

Hi I have my logo here

[image]

It’s a shape which I want to use for making some small rubber pieces. So I will use a laser to cut the outlines. The problem is that the laser accuracy is about 1mm, so the laser will not be able to cut those thin lines.

I have to find a way to make this thin parts evenly bigger. Since I have a shape and no line, it’s not possible to use the width tool.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All you need to do is add a stroke around the shape. That will increase the width of the more narrow sections. Granted, it will increase the size of all the parts, which may not be what you're looking for. How big are these "small rubber pieces" going to be?

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your suggestion :). The logo should be about 4 cm wide. Basically I have to double the thin parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using path offset (object - path - offset). This will create an offset of the whole logo. You can just delete the anchor points for the points that don't need to be any bigger.

You can also try creating a stoke only for the small parts of the logo and then use the width tool to widen the stroke to your liking. If all looks well you can expand the stroke and use the path finder options to combine the 2 shapes.

Both methods require messing with the shapes to blend the new objects to the existing logo.